# Iframe on load triggering even if iframe is not loaded on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, mobile, safari

I had problem with iframe that was loading a document using google document viewer, sometimes the document would not load.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40425780/7657853) solution to check if iframe is successfully loaded, or if it should be reloaded.

The solution works great on pc(chrome), but on iphone(safari) $('#iframe').on('load', ...) event triggers even when there is no content.

On pc on load event is only triggered when iframe is trully loaded and has content.

```
 function reloadIFrame() {
    document.getElementById("ifm").src=document.getElementById("ifm").src;
 }
 ints.push( setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 2000));

  $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('#ifm').on('load', function() {
          // this event fires even when there is no content on safari
          // ....stop reloading the iframe etc.....
          alert($('#ifm').attr('src')); // this gives me correct url, even when not loaded
```

Iframe:

```
<iframe data-iframe="true" id="ifm" data-ext="<?php echo $ext ?>" 
  class="document-iframe"  
  src="<?php echo $full_src ?>" data-tool-id="<?php echo $tool->ID ?>">
 </iframe>
```

Comment: @Lain I've added alert($('#ifm').attr('src')); to on load, and I get the proper url, even when it doesnt load

Comment: The `src` attribute is kinda static, so not very reliable. The window.location.href on the iframe shows you the actual site. Does the site (=src) exist and have content? How do you define content?

Comment: @Lain I've added the iframe html to my question, iframe src definitely exists, the problem is that google document reader fails every so often so I have to check if iframe is loaded successfully.

Comment: Well, then it seems correct to me that Safari triggers `onload`. Also be aware that Chrome does not trigger the event on download links.

Answer (score 2):

If relevant to anyone, resolved the Safari issue using the iframe element contentWindow.length. you can get more info here:
[HTMLIframeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow)

When on Safari the onLoad is activated in any case so the onLoad function makes sure content was actually loaded or needs to reload

This is my solution based on the original solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42393415/9702000)

```
iframeLoaded() {
 const contentLoaded = this.refs.iframe.contentWindow.length

 if (!!contentLoaded) {
   clearInterval(this.iframeTimeoutId)
 }
 else {
   this.updateIframeSrc()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I failed to make this work properly, so I switched to [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/) viewer instead of google document viewer. Its missing some minor features that google document viewer has, but at least it works properly every time.

```
<iframe height='100%' class="document-iframe" width='100%' scrolling='no' 
  allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() 
?>/web/viewer.html?file=<?php echo $src ?>'>
</iframe>
```