# Is there any way I can open a word document from my website on browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, office-js

I need a way to preview a word document from the website I'm building without having to download it first. I'm using Vue.js to build it

Comment: I'm not sure if OP is looking for a library or a native way to preview word documents but in either case this question is not fit for SO, I can think of a few other stack exchanges that would be a better fit

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iframe` to do this.

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=<file_url>&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

Replace `<file_url>` with you `document file url`.

Comment: fyi this service does not have a super high SLA, but there are hacks around it https://stackoverflow.com/q/40414039/8186898

Comment: Nothing is showing, I'm using  a link from firebase i.e. my files are in firebase storage